# Maxima of $f(x)/e^x$ where $f(x)$ is an approximation of $e^x$ using Stirling's

Tags: optimization, exponential-function, approximation, closed-form

Let $$f(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n}\tag1$$
and let $$g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{e^x}\tag2$$
If we plot $g(x)$ we get a graph that looks like this:
[image]

Clearly there is a maximum at around $x_0=1.5$, investigating further we find an approximation to this $x_0$ is $$x_0\approx 1.501418665538103821742229435035476066021$$
I did not manage to find a closed form using WolframAlpha or ISC.

### Questions:

1. Has a crude approximation to $e^x$ like this ever been studied? Specifically one using stirlings approximation.
2. Although I doubt it, is there any observation that can be mind that might hint at the actual value of $x_0$?
3. Is there a good way of numerically approximating $x_0$?

Comment: I do not understand the reason for that approximation to be relevant. The next step is to find stationary points for $$f_k(x)=e^{-x}\left(1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \sqrt{2\pi n} \exp\left(\frac{1}{12n+k}\right)}\right)$$ ? To which purpose?

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n A(n)$ $\quad$  with $\quad$ $\displaystyle A(n):=\prod\limits_{k=0}^\infty ((1+\frac{1}{k+n})^{k+n+\frac{1}{2}}/e)$

$\displaystyle f(x):=1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}A(n)$ $\quad$ with $\quad$ $\displaystyle A(1)=\frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ $\quad$ and $\quad$ 
$\displaystyle \frac{A(n)}{A(n+1)}=(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+\frac{1}{2}}/e$

Maximum for $\displaystyle e^{-x}f(x)$: $\quad$ $\displaystyle (f(x)e^{-x})´=f´(x)e^{-x}-f(x)e^{-x}:=0$

=> $\quad$ $\displaystyle f´(x)=f(x)$ $\quad$ which means $\quad$ $\displaystyle 1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}A(n)= A(1)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}A(n+1)$.

An iteration to get the value $x$ is e.g.

$$\displaystyle x_{k+1}=\frac{A(1)-1}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{x_k^{n-1}}{n!}(A(n)-A(n+1))}$$ with $\quad$ $x_0:=1,5$.

$\displaystyle A(n)-A(n+1)$ converges quickly, therefore there are not many members of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{n!}(A(n)-A(n+1))$ for the iteration necessary to get a good result for $x$.